# Unable to insert any data to the database using python

Tags: python, sqlite, relational-database

```
import sqlite3

def create_a_new_table():
    Myschool = sqlite3.connect('normal database for experiment purpose.db')
    curschool = Myschool.cursor()
    curschool.execute("""
                           CREATE TABLE new_Basic_Player_Info
                           (
                              Ranking INTEGER,
                              Player_name TEXT,

                              Country TEXT,
                              Speciality TEXT,
                              Value INTEGER,
                              Cost INTEGER
                            );
                      """)
    Myschool.close()


def insert_data():
    Myschool = sqlite3.connect('normal database for experiment for purpose.db')
    curschool = Myschool.cursor()
   # nm = input("Enter the name of the player: ")
    sql = """INSERT INTO TABLE new_Basic_Player_Info(Ranking, Player_name) 
        VALUES(%s, %s);"""
```

May be %s, %s is the problem.
Or, sql named string should be ended with a semi-colon(;)
The main code that is not being executed

```
try:
    curschool.execute(sql, (1, "aNIKET GHOSH"))
    Myschool.commit()
    Myschool.close()

except:
    Myschool.rollback()
```

even I have used try and except keywords too.

```
create_a_new_table()
insert_data()
```

Comment: Stop catching and hiding all the errors and always rolling back. Remove that try/except and let Python tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: I struggled with similar errors/issues when grappling with pymysql. I realized it is best to use Flask's ORM implementation, Flask-SQLAlchemy as it abstracts any differences between different SQL variants and has well-supported [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. I found three issues.

One issue which is that you are using two different sqlite files (missing a "for" in the first one). A good trick is to always think about DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Two issues with your insert statement:

1. `INSERT INTO TABLE ...` whereas the correct syntax is `INSERT INTO ...`
2. You are using `%s` instead of the correct syntax `?`

I.e. replace

`sql = """INSERT INTO TABLE new_Basic_Player_Info(Ranking, Player_name) VALUES(%s, %s);"""`

with

`sql = """INSERT INTO new_Basic_Player_Info(Ranking, Player_name) VALUES(?, ?);"""`

and you will be on track again.

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine for me. Those two was the major errors into the code.